# Unix Sockets : AF_LOCAL vs AF_INET

Tags: c, unix, unix-socket

I'm just starting with socket programming in UNIX and I was reading the man pages for the socket system call. I'm a bit confused about the AF_LOCAL argument and when it is used. The manual just says local communication. Wouldn't an AF_INET format also work for local communication?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`AF_LOCAL` uses UNIX domain sockets which are local to the filesystem and can be used for internal communications. `AF_INET` is an IP socket. `AF_LOCAL` will not incur some performance penalties related to sending data over IP. See this [old but very nice discussion](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-performance/2005-February/001143.html) of the topic.