# Domain argument to socket() and socketpair()

Tags: linux, sockets

I've been studying Linux socket programming recently, and the concepts are still swirling and unsettled in my head. Can someone confirm or correct my understanding of the `domain` argument to `socket()` and `socketpair()`: one should choose `PF_LOCAL` (or `PF_UNIX`) if one wants the socket communication to be strictly within the same computer, and one should choose `PF_INET` if the socket communication is meant to be between different computers -- is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the communications domain you want to use. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) for `socket`. For example, `AF_INET` means v4 internet protocols, `AF_INET6` means v6 internet protocols, `AF_APPLETALK` means AppleTalk, and so forth. You almost certainly want `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.

Whether the other program you'll be communicating with is on the same machine or not isn't really relevant since you can communicate with the local host just fine using internet protocols.

However, there is a small performance penalty associated with using the internet domain protocols. If your application will be connecting *only* with other applications on the same machine, using the `AF_LOCAL/AF_UNIX` domain will be faster and will offer you some additional advantages such as file-level security controls on the sockets. Just be aware that you won't be able to use your code between different computers without modifying it if you go that route.

A good discussion of the pros and cons of this choice can be found [here](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-performance/2005-February/001143.html).

Comment: In which case, what's the purpose of the `PF_LOCAL` domain, and when should you use it? (My reading material said to prefer `PF_*` as the argument to `socket()`, and to prefer `AF_*` as the value assigned to the `struct sockaddr_*` family) - but I get that `PF_*` is currently generally equal to `AF_*`.

Comment: @StoneThrow See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288206/unix-sockets-af-local-vs-af-inet

Comment: I think the discussions you pointed me to effectively say that local communications can be done with either `PF_LOCAL` or `PF_INET`, but using the latter has performance penalties, and that nonlocal communication must be done using `PF_INET` - is that right? That's what I meant in my question, sorry if I didn't articulate as well as possible.

Comment: @StoneThrow Edited to (hopefully) clarify.